# Spring Rest Controller: how to selectively switch off validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-web

In my controller I have a method for creating an entity

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
...
@RestController
public class Controller {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)  
  public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO) {
  ...
```

with

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
...
public class RequestDTO
    @NotEmpty // (1)
    private String field1;
    //other fields, getters and setters.
```

I want to add a controller method

```
update(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO)
```

but in this method it should be allowed for `field1` to be empty or null, i.e. the line

```
@NotEmpty // (1)
```

of the `RequestDTO` should be ignored.

How can I do this? Do I have to write a class that looks exactly the same like `RequestDTO`, but does not have the annotation? Or is it somehow possible via inheritance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: Use *Validation Groups*:

```
@NotEmpty(groups = SomeCriteria.class)
private String field1;
```

And reference your intended group in method handler parameters:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Validated(SomeCriteria.class) @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO)
```

In the above example, validations in the `SomeCriteria` group will be applied and others going to be ignored. Usually, these validation groups are defined as empty interfaces:

```
public interface SomeCriteria {}
```

You can read more about these group constraints in [Hibernate Validator documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/ch05.html).