# How to change DTO validation parameters based on @RestController method used in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, validation

When I add a new Category, I use a CategoryDTO class, 
which contains a parameter friendlyUrl validated by @FriendlyURL validator:

```
    @FriendlyURL(exists = false, message = "error.friendly.url.already.exists")
    private String friendlyUrl;
```

When I update the Category I want to use the same CategoryDTO with @FriendlyURL validator but now with options `exists=true' and message = "error.friendly.url.not.found"

```
    @FriendlyURL(exists = true, message = "error.friendly.url.not.found")
```

Is this possible or should I create a new DTO for the update method?

Comment: Did you try using *Validation Groups*? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704351/spring-rest-controller-how-to-selectively-switch-off-validation

Comment: @AliDehghani I have just read the documentation from top to bottom on Grouping constraints and I can't find a way to do what I want.