# @RequestBody validation with Jackson @JsonView and @Valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, bean-validation

I have a POJO which I'm trying to reuse between 2 different modules (and will be used by 2 different controller methods in separate projects). I'm trying to apply a specific view on it in the controller method, so that the string `thing` will go through bean validation if it's scoped to a specific `JsonView`:

```
public class TestPojo {

    @JsonView(Views.TestView.class)
    @NotNull(message = "can't be empty")
    @JsonProperty
    private String thing;
}
```

My controller method is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/test", method = POST)
public String test(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.TestView.class) @Valid TestPojo request) {
    // omitted 
}
```

This validates fine, but if I change the above `@JsonView` to for example:

```
@JsonView(Views.OtherView.class)
```

I was then hoping it would no longer validate the variable `thing` because it's part of a different view. However in reality it's resolved to `null` (as you'd expect) but still gets validated and rejected.

Is there any way to get this to work as I'm hoping, or an easier way to do this that I've totally missed?

Comment: You can use *[Validation Groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html)*  like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704351/spring-rest-controller-how-to-selectively-switch-off-validation

Comment: That solves my problem, thank you sir!